# What will happen if a framework get deleted from an app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I was asked a question, what will happen when a framework is accidentally deleted from your device may be iphone or mac?

Whether your application crash or it will work without any error?

Please provide me answer with explainations.

Comment: If this was a job-interview question you might want to add job-interview tag. It exists but was not used yet. It might be useful if certain questions would be marked as such. (just an opinion)

Comment: @rokjarc We're not using that tag anymore; it's not relevant to programming, really. Think of tags as being something that a programmer would have expertise in and would want to 'follow' to look for questions on.

Comment: @Anoop see my comment above; I'm removing the interview-question tag.

Comment: @AndrewBarber : Ok not an issue, I thought it will make others to filter/search. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yup, NP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get linking error.  If framework folder is inside the application means its runtime linking.

> OS X embeds an "install name" inside each dynamic library. This
>   install name is the path to where the library can be found when dyld
>   needs to load it. When you build an application that links against a
>   dynamic library, this install name is copied into the application
>   binary. When the application runs, the copied install name is then
>   used to locate the library or framework.

```
   $ otool -D /Applications/Google\ Drive.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python 
    /Applications/Google Drive.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
```

so if you will delete Frameworks folder you will get Dyld Error.

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
  Referenced from: /Applications/Transmission.app/Contents/MacOS/Transmission
  Reason: image not found
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If a framework is deleted, only software linking to that framework would be affected.
If it is a system framework, expect your system to start failing.
If it is a 3rd party framework, it should be limited in scope of impact.
If it is in your app bundle, and your app is code-signed, the removal of the bundled framework should prevent your app from launching.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the application needs access to the framework you have removed.
If you application requires the framework then it will not compile.
If you dont need it, it will just compile like normal.